# R PortfolioAnalytics create.EfficientFrontier() confusion over custom expected returns

Tags: r, r-portfolioanalytics

**BACKGROUND:** I wonder if you can help me. I am familiar with portfolio optimisation. I am not an expert but I do usually build my own optimisers to make efficient frontiers, based on quadprog or numerical methods. I am just starting to use PortfolioAnalytics as it looks really good and I am interested in the different solvers available.

**OBJECTIVE:** I want to compute the second moment of asset returns (and higher) using a set of historical returns but to specify the first moment (i.e. use my own expected returns). I have specified expected returns as instructed in the package documentation and vignettes.

**ISSUE:** I do not understand what create.EfficientFrontier() is doing. I put in my own expected returns and the efficient frontier does not change. To test what is going on, (i) I put in much higher expected returns as a test, and the frontier does not rise; but (ii) the input is doing something, because if I zero-out the highest-returning asset, the frontier contracts; and (iii) if I reverse the order of expected returns so that more volatile assets have lower expected returns, the frontier changes.

**QUESTION:** I would really appreciate it if anyone could tell me how to make a frontier using my own expected returns rather than the default historical returns.

Many thanks indeed,

John

**Reproducible example**

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

#Load packages

library(quadprog)
library(lubridate)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ROI.plugin.quadprog)

#Create some fake data (no doubt there is an easier way of doing this)

set.seed(1234)
fakereturns<-matrix(rnorm(10,1.01^(1/12)-1,0.01/(5*sqrt(12))),nrow=10,ncol=1)

for(i in 2:5){

  fakereturns <- cbind(fakereturns,matrix(rnorm(10,(1+i/100)^(1/12)-1,i/(500*sqrt(12))),nrow=10,ncol=1))
}

fakedates<-as.Date(as.yearmon(seq.Date(as.Date('2019-01-01'),by='month',length.out = 10)),frac=1)
R<-xts(fakereturns,fakedates)
names(R)<-c("stock1","stock2","stock3","stock4","stock5")

#Set up portfolio spec

pspec <- portfolio.spec(assets=names(R))
pspec <- add.constraint(pspec,type="weight_sum", min_sum=1, max_sum=1)
pspec <- add.constraint(pspec,type="box",min=rep(0,5),max=rep(1,5))

#Chart efficient frontier using historical data

portfolio<-pspec
eff_example <- create.EfficientFrontier(R=R, portfolio=portfolio, type="mean-StdDev")
chart.EfficientFrontier(eff_example, match.col="StdDev",type="l")

#(i) Specify much higher expected returns to make the frontier rise

exp.returns <- (1+seq(0.06,0.1,by=0.01))^(1/12)-1
num_assets <- length(exp.returns)
momentargs <- list()
momentargs$mu <-  matrix(exp.returns, nrow=num_assets, ncol=1 )

#Plot (i) as red circles -- why are these not above the first frontier?

eff_example_moments <- create.EfficientFrontier(R=R, portfolio=portfolio, type="mean-StdDev", momentargs=momentargs)
extract<-eff_example_moments$frontier
points(extract[,1]~extract[,2],col="red")

#(ii) Zero out the highest-returning asset's expected return to see what happens

exp.returns <- (1+c(0.01,0.02,0,0.04,0))^(1/12)-1
num_assets <- length(exp.returns)
momentargs <- list()
momentargs$mu <-  matrix(exp.returns, nrow=num_assets, ncol=1 )

#Plot (ii) as green circles -- why are these on the first frontier?

eff_example_moments <- create.EfficientFrontier(R=R, portfolio=portfolio, type="mean-StdDev", momentargs=momentargs)
extract<-eff_example_moments$frontier
points(extract[,1]~extract[,2],col="green")

#(iii) Reverse the order of expected returns to see what happens

exp.returns <- (1+seq(0.05,0.01,by=-0.01))^(1/12)-1
num_assets <- length(exp.returns)
momentargs <- list()
momentargs$mu <-  matrix(exp.returns, nrow=num_assets, ncol=1 )

#Plot (iii) as blue circles -- now we are off the original frontier, but why?

eff_example_moments <- create.EfficientFrontier(R=R, portfolio=portfolio, type="mean-StdDev", momentargs=momentargs)
extract<-eff_example_moments$frontier
points(extract[,1]~extract[,2],col="blue")
legend("bottomright",legend=c("Rtns increased by 0.05 annualised","Some zeroed out","Exp rtns reversed"),lwd=1,col=c(2,3,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I think the fundamental problem here is that the `$mu` element of the `moments` list is only passed through to the underlying optimisers by the `optimize.portfolio` function if a return objective is specified. If a risk objective is specified, `$mu` is not used.

To make an efficient frontier I have hacked the `optimize.portfolio` function by adding some code that puts `$mu` in, as follows:

```
 ## A line of existing code to show where I put this

 moments <- list(mean = rep(0, N))

 ## My added bit, straight after the above

if (!is.null(mout$mu)) {
  moments[["mean"]] <- as.vector(mout$mu)
}

## My bit ends
```

I can then optimise by minimising standard deviation for a given target return. I then iterate through target returns to create an efficient frontier (rather than using the `create.EfficientFrontier` function).